# How to bind multiple data models to TableView in RxSwift

Tags: swift, alamofire, rx-swift, swift5

I am studying RxSwift.
But it's very difficult, so I post a question.

Situation :
I want to display the information of the character in tableView.
The character has item information and avatar information. (There are two APIs.)

Problem :
I succeeded in displaying one data model (item information) in tableView.
But I don't know how to bind two or more models to tableView.

This is the code when I bind one model to tableView.

ViewModel :

```
let characterDetail = PublishSubject<CharacterDetailResp>()
var characterDetailInfo : CharacterDetailResp = CharacterDetailResp()
let error : PublishSubject<CharacterDetailError> = PublishSubject()

func requestData() {
        let URL : String = "\(baseUrl)/servers/characterName/"

        AF.request(URL, method: .get, parameters:nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default).responseObject {
        (response : DataResponse<CharacterDetailResp>) in

        switch response.result {
        case .success:
            self.characterDetailInfo = response.value!
            self.characterDetail.onNext(self.characterDetailInfo)

        case .failure(let err):
            if err.localizedDescription == "The Internet connection appears to be offline." {
                self.error.onNext(.internetError("Please Check Internet"))
            }
            else {
                self.error.onNext(.serverMessage(err.localizedDescription))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

ViewController :

```
var characterDetailViewModel = ViewModel()
let characterDetail = PublishSubject<CharacterDetailResp>()
let disposeBag = DisposeBag()

func setupBindings() {
        characterDetailViewModel
            .error
            .observeOn(MainScheduler.instance)
            .subscribe(onNext: { (error) in
                switch error {
                case .internetError(let message):
                    print("Error : \(message)")
                case .serverMessage(let message):
                    print("Warning : \(message)")
                }
            })
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)

        tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "CharacterCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: String(describing: CharacterCell.self))

        characterDetailViewModel
            .characterDetail
            .observeOn(MainScheduler.instance)
            .bind(to: tableView.rx.items(cellIdentifier: "CharacterCell", cellType: CharacterCell.self)) {
                (row, characterDetail, cell) in
                cell.character = characterDetail
            }
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)
    }
```

I want to know how to bind two or more API models to TableView

Plz help me....

Comment: What do you want to so? Do you need to show two different cell in your tableview for example? Or it is just some cells wrapped with a header? Please elaborate more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to implement something very much like this. Here's what I did:

```
final class SearchDataSource: NSObject, RxTableViewDataSourceType, UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, observedEvent: Event<SearchResult>) {
        switch observedEvent {
        case .next(let result):
            searchResult = result
            tableView.reloadData()
        case .error(let error):
            fatalError(error.localizedDescription)
        case .completed:
            break
        }
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 2
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        switch section {
        case 0:
            return searchResult.titles.count
        case 1:
            return searchResult.bodies.count
        default:
            fatalError("too many sections")
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        switch indexPath.section {
        case 0:
            let segment = searchResult.titles[indexPath.row]
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Title", for: indexPath) as! TitleTableViewCell
            cell.configure(with: segment)
            return cell
        case 1:
            let segment = searchResult.bodies[indexPath.row]
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Body", for: indexPath) as! BodyTableViewCell
            cell.configure(with: segment)
            return cell
        default:
            fatalError("too many sections")
        }
    }

    var searchResult = SearchResult(titles: [], bodies: [])
}

final class TitleTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    func configure(with segment: TitleSegment) { }
}

final class BodyTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    func configure(with segment: BodySegment) { }
}

struct SearchResult {
    let titles: [TitleSegment]
    let bodies: [BodySegment]
}

struct TitleSegment {
    let sectionID: Int
    let title: String
}

struct BodySegment {
    let sectionTitle: String
    let sectionID: Int
    let text: String
}
```

And here's how to use it:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let viewModel = viewModelFactory(self)

    viewModel.searchResult
        .bind(to: tableView.rx.items(dataSource: SearchDataSource()))
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)
}
```

Comment: I haven't tried, but I know this is close to the correct answer. Thank you for your answer!